# how to get jquery to run repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a piece of jquery code that looks for a specific URL (with an anchor at the end) and runs a function if it has a match. The code only runs once, if this is the first URL loaded. Is it possible to have the following code running until it has a match?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/datahealthcheck16-test/index.html#backup-section-3";
   $(function(){
        if (location.href==url){
            paintLine(); 
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Run a while loop until a match is found?

Comment: That's confusing, how would the `location.href` **ever** be more than one URL ?

Comment: Oh wait, you wanna check the ***hash***, if so, you'd use the `hashchange` event for that.

Comment: Incidentally, `$(function(){` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){`. You don't need both. See [Using jQuery Core](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: @adeneo I'm pretty sure that's what OP is after. This question is too vague, and the code is head-scratching.

Comment: we can call functions repeatedly, it can be done by invoking a function that calls itself again and again, but how it gonna change url to campare with specific url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only runs the first time, because changing the hash does not fire the DOM ready handler again, it does however fire the `hashchange` event.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if ( window.location.hash === '#backup-section-3' ) {
        paintLine();
    }
}).trigger('hashchange'); // fire on first load as well
```

Note that the `window` is always available, and does not need a DOM ready handler

Comment: where `hashchange` event is available? I mean browsers/frameworks/etc...

Comment: For reference, see [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange).

Comment: well, it has pretty good browser compatibility. will use it =)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setTimeout()` function to run your function, for example every second:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/datahealthcheck16-test/index.html#backup-section-3";

   function test() {
      if (location.href == url) {
         paintLine();
      } else {
         setTimeout(test, 1000);
      }
   }
   test();
});
```

but what is your idea, behind your code? I sure there is more convenient ways to do your task.

Comment: yep, but if `location.href == url` loop will end

Comment: that's exactly what needed by author of question: *Is is possible to have the following code running until it has a match?*

Comment: I agree, that this approach is not the best idea but it solves problem, and you can see me askin him after my code.

Comment: so neither location.href nor url gonna change, hence infinite loop will be called

Comment: you can give it a try before any further comment, means no offense pls

Comment: why don't you just give it a shot if you are so sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122345/discussion-between-spirit-and-muhammad-irfan).

Comment: your code will only work without ending up in loop if the user fortunately click on the link that has same hash as in the url variable, all other clicks will end up in loop \

Comment: 100% correct. that's why I ask him about his idea, to porpose more adequate solution =)

Comment: If you're just going to call a function over and over again, why not use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` - the former is meant for _exactly_ that job.

Comment: `setInterval` sometime can produce undesired result. for example, if your functions executes more than 5 ms, say 300 ms, than you will have 700 ms beetwen function calls. And what if for some reason your function will lasts for 1100 ms? `setTimeout` doesn have such issue.

Answer (score 0):

using adeneo's answer:

here is what matches your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/datahealthcheck16-test/index.html#backup-section-3";
   $(function(){
        if (location.href==url){
            paintLine(); 
        }
    });
   $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if ( location.href == url ) {
            paintLine();
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: `$(function(){` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){`. Using both is redundant. See [Using jQuery Core](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).